# Issue using open() in Python 3.2.3

Tags: python

I am having issues with the open() function in Python 3.2.3. The following code works well using 2.7.3, but not with Python 3:

```
    file = open("text.txt", 'r')
```

In Python3, it gives me a standard IOError:

```
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'
```

Note that the text.txt file that is referenced is in the same directory as the python file.

Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error message? If so, what?

Comment: How does it fail?  Does it through a syntax error, IOError, or something else?  Can you provide a stack trace.  It's hard to decode the answer when we don't have anything to go on.

Comment: added the error. text.txt is definitely in the same directory as the python file trying to open it. In addition, I am using Eclipse with Pydev

Comment: What does `os.getcwd()` return?

Comment: It has definitely something to do with current working directory.

Comment: you're both probably right. how do I run that command?

Comment: scratch that, i imported os and ran it right above that line in my python script. My problem was that my python script and the text file were both located within a package within an eclipse project, whereas open looks for a file on the project level, not inside the package. Thank you!

Comment: Don't post the answer as an edit. Post it as an answer, and accept it after the time delay allows it. In this case, if you don't think the question will help anyone else, you can just delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file name is not relative to the directory of the file, but your [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_working_directory) (which you can find out with [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os-file-dir)).

If you want to open a file whose name is relative to your Python file, you can use the magic variable [`__file__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-49), like this:

```
import os.path
fn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'text.txt')
with open(fn, 'r') as file:
   # Do something, like ...
   print(file.read())
```

Comment: In Python 3, one should probably be using pathlib.Path, no? Then again I landed here trying to figure out why open() doesn't work on a Path...

Comment: This question is about python 3.2, where pathlib is not present yet. Why don't you [ask your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a file in read mode, and this file has to exist.

Perhaps problem is that the file just doesn't exist in your python3 path and therefore the open command fails, but 'text.txt' exist on your python2.7 lib (or somewhere in python2.7 path) and this is why python is able to locate the file and open it.

You can just try this code (this will assure you the file exist since you create it):

```
f = open('text.txt','w')
f.close()
f.open('text.txt','r')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Eclipse with Pydev, and had the text.txt file within the package instead of on the project level. To access a file within the package, you need to use:

```
 file = open("[package]/text.txt", 'r')
```